# Getting stock prices from google finance onto webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Would it be possible to use Javascript to pull stock prices off of google finance and post onto my website? Or would I need to use a different language to do this and have javascript grab and post?

Comment: A backend language like `php`/`c#`/`java` should be used because the api token should not be shown on the client side

Comment: @MaartenDev Why don't use NodeJS? OP asks if it is possible to do using Javascript.

Comment: NodeJS is fine, i just forgot about it, thanks for the reminder :) @vHawk